# How to add object to an NSPointerArray?

Tags: ios, swift, nspointerarray

I want to store weak references in an `NSPointerArray` but I get an error:

```
public var objectWithReloadFRC = NSPointerArray(options: NSPointerFunctionsWeakMemory)
objectWithReloadFRC.addPointer(self) //self is an UIViewController subclass
```

[image]

tried this too:

```
objectWithReloadFRC.addPointer(UnsafePointer(self)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get a pointer to the storage used for an object with
`unsafeAddressOf()`. Since `addPointer()` requires a *mutable* pointer,
another conversion is needed:

```
objectWithReloadFRC.addPointer(UnsafeMutablePointer(unsafeAddressOf(self)))
```

**Swift 3:**

```
var objectWithReloadFRC = NSPointerArray(options: .weakMemory)
objectWithReloadFRC.addPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
```